# create dynamic object in jquery

Tags: jquery, oop

I want to create dynamic object in jquery and use like this :

```
var list=Array();
var Object={id,name};
$.each(....){
   //some code
   $.each(...){
      Object o=new Object();
      o.id=$(this).val();
   }
   //some code
   $.each(...){
      Object o=new Object();
      o.id=$(this).val();
   }
   //some code
}
```

How?

[Edited]

I Want to create an instance from an object that created dynamically
For example i create an object like this :

```
x
{
   id,
   value,
   state,
   name
}
```

And later i use it:

```
x sample=new x();
x.id=2;
x.name="taghi";
x.state=true;
x.value=3;
```

Comment: question too vague.. please add more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery you can create tags like this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var inputElement;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            inputElement = $("<input/>", { class: "btn", id: "btn" + i, value: "click" });
            $("body").append(inputElement);
        }
    });
```

Take this as an example. Change the tag names according to your need

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
var output = []
$('.grab').each(function(index) { 
    var obj = {}
    obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
    output.push(obj)
})
Happy coding.

Also, consider using .map():

var output = $('.grab').map(function() { 
    var obj = {}
    obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
    return obj
})
```

Comment: The literal-object syntax cannot be used for non-literal keys. To use a non-literal key with an object requires the object[keyExpression] notation, as below. (This is equivalent to object.key when keyExpression = "key", but note the former case takes an expression as the key and the latter an identifier.)